# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la relation « id_statut_produit_seq » n'existe pas

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

In my project i need to automatically generate the id of each entity so i have created a sequence in each entity to complete the task, but unfortunately this problem is displayed every time i click on the button to submit the form.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la relation « id_statut_produit_seq » n'existe pas
  Position : 17
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:116) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]...
```

Here is the class and the sequence:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATUT_PRODUITS",schema = "PACKOUT")
public class StatutProduits implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID_STATUT_PRODUIT")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idStatutProduit")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "idStatutProduit", sequenceName = "idStatutProduit_SEQ",allocationSize = 1, initialValue =1)

    private BigDecimal idStatutProduit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the sequence `id_statut_produit_seq` in your PostreSQL database:

```
-- script to create the sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE id_statut_produit_seq START 1 INCREMENT 1;
```

But I think you can have the automatically generated id in a easier way:

**PostreSQL:**

```
-- create the sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE id_statut_produit_seq START 1 INCREMENT 1;

-- create the table
CREATE TABLE statut_produits (
  id_statut_produit bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_statut_produit_seq'::regclass)
);
```

**Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATUT_PRODUITS",schema = "PACKOUT")
public class StatutProduits implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idStatutProduit;
}
```